# PHPMailer - can I check SMTP hourly message limit and swap to another smtp Settings, make limit and so on?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I want to make my own email sending app. I am using MyMailer in WordPress with 5 different SMTP settings. But cron seems to be locked every couple min on my server. Wish to make my own app but need to send couple thousands emails a day.

Limit is 500 per hour for each smtp account. Need to swap after I get "limit reached" to another SMTP and so on. If I reach hourly limit for all smtp accounts, I wish to wait hour and start process again.

I can setup cron manually to run script which can check if first SMTP account limit is again available and start sending messages again.

Comment: "No worries ... it not spam site."  Thank goodness you're not spamming folks!

Comment: What do you mean by "corn"? If you need to send lots, pay for it, or get a better host.

Comment: hahah "corn" , cron I mean :) @Synchro2

Comment: Can you have your script randomly select from the SMTP settings? That way each time you send an email it will be distributed across all your SMTP accounts. And ideally you will avoid the limit this way.

Comment: Yes. No spam. I have my site since 1998 when I was in school. Collected loads of emails since then. Now checked which still exists and wish to send newsletter to all my members. At the beginning site was fully based on tables and was static. My nephew changed it to very first version of PHP somehow in beginning of Y2k+couple years. Now is in Wordpress. 

Anyway ... thanks for trying to help. Sorry for CORN again. Maybe I was hungry that time.

Comment: Thanks @Voski I was thinking to make an array of all SMTP hosts settings I have and set max allowed emails per hour.

Comment: Thanks @Voski I was thinking to make an array of all SMTP hosts settings I have and set max allowed emails per hour.
Then I would set array variable within each SMTP setting to hold time of last sent message from that host. 
Loop will check how many msg I have sent from each SMTP ... what was the time of last sent msg from that host ... If I can't use that SMTP , loop would chose another SMTP from array and make check ... if I can send msg from this one ... I would control msg count for given time and if I get to the limit ... I would write down time of last msg . Cron every 10 min to this.

Comment: Crone will run this script every 10-20 or 30 min to check if any SMTP is available a the moment.

Comment: @Severo I was thinking of something a lot simpler. 

Have an array of your settings. Each time you send an email randomly pick one of those settings. Now if you can get an idea of the rate of emails you send you should be able to come up with a rough idea of how many SMPT settings you need.

Lets say you can send 1 email per hour per setting. On average you send 1 email every hour. So if you ignore for spikes in the rate of email requests you can get by with one setting.